# MongoDB Sharded cluster: Inserts only hitting one shard

Tags: mongodb

We are using a cluster with 6 shards.

The collection uses a **non-hashed** key.

The documents are rather big and our `chunk-size` is set to **512MB**.

Two huge bulk inserts hit our cluster but everything is inserted on a single shard.
This leads to 120% effective lock, while the other shards are chilling at 5% lock.

I think that the *bulk inserts* only append the last chunk since the *inserts are ordered*. Due to heavy load there is no redistribution of chunks until the insert ends.

After the bulk insert redistribution works nicely.

MongoDB version is 2.6.5.

How can I configure the config servers to automatically distribute bulk inserts?

I will edit the post if more information is required.

Thank You all!!!

### As answered below:

pre-splitting is the best solution for us. This allows us to evenly distribute the whole set before insertion since we know the key space! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your shard key is *monotonic*? The [documentation has a large section about bulk insert in sharded environments](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#strategies-for-bulk-inserts-to-a-sharded-collection).

Essentially,

1. either [pre-split the collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/split-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/)
2. or insert to different mongos (not for the initial insert)
3. and/or make sure that your shard key doesn't increase monotonically (for non-hashed collections, that's usually a good idea).